# Make the led work only if a certain voltage exceeded

Tags: led

How could I make the led work only if a certain voltage exceeded?

I have four voltage regulators in my project to supply my ICs, and i want to put 2 leds on the box so i know if my regulators giving +15V and +5V.
 I need to down it for 4 led, so it need to be simple .
I try to make a comparator with op amp but i cold not.

Comment: Do you want to know if they're within a certain tolerance, or just that the voltages are present?

Comment: Show us what you tried with the comparator, because the solution will be similar. The best way to learn is to understand where you went wrong.

Comment: @MattYoung I want the led to works if the input is equal r more than 15V , if it is less , it have to turn off. and the same for 5V. I I connect the led with the output of the voltage regulator the brightness will be changing, but what i need is on or off sate only.

Comment: @jippie I used a normal opamp comparator but it could not be done because I cannot  set the threshold

Comment: Thus? Show us what you did, including the partnumbers you used. Click edit, hit Ctrl-M and start drawing.

Comment: a comparator is exactly what you want to build, and it can be done with an op-amp. Show us what you did and the result you got, and we can help you get to a working solution.

Comment: Which opamp are you using, and how much current do your LEDS need to light up properly?

Answer (score 4):

As the earlier comments and answer pointed out, if you want an accurate indication of voltage level, you need an accurate reference.

The more normal method is to use a voltage reference and multiple comparitors or op-amps to compare your input voltages to the reference.  The output of the comparitors or op-amps would then drive the LEDs.

However, there is a simple trick that is inexpensive and very simple.  It works best with positive voltages but can be made to work with negative voltages with some effort.  Because you want to measure only two positive voltages, I'll offer it as a solution for you.

It uses only 3 resistors, a LED, and a TL431 adjustable shunt regulator per voltage rail to be monitored.  Very simple and quite accurate.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0Dkxl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The TL431 is normally intended to be an adjustable shunt regulator - sort of an adjustable zener diode.  It contains an accurate 2.5V reference and is normally configured so that the cathode connects to the voltage to be regulated.

But it will happily run open-loop.  In that case, the TL431 has a high impedance from the cathode to the anode so long as the adjust pin voltage is less than the internal 2.5V reference.  When the adjust pin voltage is more than the internal 2.5V reference, the cathode has a low impedance between itself and the anode.

It is that low impedance that turns the LED ON.

You will need to set the voltage divider ratio on the adjust pin so that the TL431 conducts when the input voltage is above your desired value.

Duplicate the circuit for each voltage rail to be monitored.

Comment: How would you make this work for the exact opposite scenario where the LED should light up when the voltage drops below a certain value?

Answer (score 2):

You need a voltage reference that will work from one of the supplies. Let's say you use a series 2.5V reference. That's like an accurate 2.5V voltage regulator that is only capable of a relatively small current.

Now to compare your supply voltages to that, you'll need to divide them down so that they equal 2.500V at the minimum voltage you consider acceptable.

Let's say that's 4.5V for the 5V supply and 13V for the 15V supply. So you calculate out the resistors for those two dividers. Say 800 ohms and 1k and 4.2K and 1K. Then you have to do some work to figure out the tolerances of the resistors and the reference the comparator offset and decide whether you can just buy resistors and an accurate reference or whether you need to add some trimpots to adjust the thresholds.

Then you can use a dual comparator and drive the LEDs with them. If you don't want the LEDs to flicker near the threshold then you can add a bit of positive feedback so maybe the LEDs turn on at 4.5V but off at 4.4V. That's a bit more complex and you can leave that for later.

Comment: "You need a voltage reference " that what i am saying , i do not have a voltage reference. I am getting the voltage form a varying power supply 23-40V   and after it input the regulators I get +15V and +5V.  Could I use a controlled voltage transistor, MOSFET  and I set the gate voltage when it turn on ?

Comment: What I mean is that "You need a voltage reference". A MOSFET gate threshold is a voltage reference, just a really, really crummy one. If you want to know whether it's higher than 2-4V maybe it's good enough for you. If you want to distinguish 4.5V from 4.4V, it's not likely to give you a good stable result.